# count an element in a list with list inside in python

Tags: python, list, count

I have a list with one list inside and I would like to count how many times is one element repeat. for example:

```
list = ['a','b','c',['a','d']]
find = 'a'
list.count(find)
```

The ouptput is 1, but I'm looking for 2.

There is any easy way to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Archive with `chain.from_iterable`

```
from itertools import chain
print(list(chain.from_iterable(lst)).count('a'))
```

First make your list flatten and get the count.